# Is there a notation for saying that $x_n\geq c$ from some $n$ and on?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I am looking for something like $\lim\inf x_n \geq c$, but I need that from some point and on it is $\geq c$, not just that the limit is $\geq c$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the word *eventually* to describe this scenario; for example, you would say that the sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ is eventually bounded below by $c$.

Answer (score 3):

As @user notes, the usual term for this notion is "eventually" (introduced or anyway popularized by Kelley in his book *General Topology*). It's a quantifier, sometimes written $\forall^*$. For any predicate $P(n)$ of integers, $P(n)$ holds eventually (with respect to $n$) iff $(\forall^* n)\, P(n) := (\exists N)(\forall n\ge N)\, P(n)$.

If you need to use the notion a lot, you could make up a notation, such as
$$
(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} \le^* (y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} := (\forall^* n\in \Bbb N)\, x_n \le y_n.
$$
with the understanding that a real $c$ used as a sequence, as in $(y_n)\, ^*{\ge}\, c$, stands for the constantly-$c$ sequence. Note that $\le^*$ is a preorder — it's reflexive and transitive.

Just as an aside, the dual notion to "eventually" is "frequently" (again, Kelley's term): $P(n)$ holds frequently (w.r.t. $n$) means $(\forall N)(\exists n\ge N)\,P(n)$. Over the integers, it's equivalent to "$P(n)$ holds infinitely often". If we write $\exists^*$ for "frequently", then these two quantifiers obey the familiar rules: $\forall^* = \lnot \exists^*\lnot$ and $\exists^* = \lnot \forall^*\lnot$, as is easily verified:
$$\begin{align}
\lnot (\exists^* n)\lnot P(n)&\iff \lnot (\forall N)(\exists n\ge N)\lnot P(n) \\
&\iff (\exists N)(\forall n\ge N)\lnot\lnot P(n) \\
&\iff (\forall^* n) P(n). \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for a notation like $$\forall \, n \ge N_0  : x_n \ge c$$
where $\forall$ means "for all" and $N_0$ is the "some point and on" chosen by you.

Comment: You really shouldn't write it like that.

Comment: If anything, I would go for $\forall n\geq N_0:x_n\geq c$, to respect the agreed-upon way of writing quantifiers. It then should be implicit that $N_0$ is some number, but please - quantifiers first.

Comment: @Wojowu I didn't know of any such way of writing quantifiers. Thanks for informing me. I have tried to correct it. Is it okay now?

Comment: @tomasz Is this better ? I have tried correcting it as Wojowu said.

Comment: Yes, definitely. The spacing looks a bit odd, and I can't recall the colon being used in any actual mathematical text, but it's not wrong. Still, if you're writing it formally like that, I'd say it would be better to actually write the whole thing, like $\exists N_0\forall n\geq N_0 \ \ x_n\geq c$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen things like "$x_n \ge c$ for all $n \gg 1$", but using words is definitely clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *"for all sufficiently large $n$"* works also. If you want more detail (not necessary in my opinion) you can say that there exists $N$ such that $x_n\ge c$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: @Ihf Yes, correct. Thank you, I edited.